# When not to use local scope functions?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, closures

Recently I've been doing a code review for a developer, and we ended up in a discussion, about using or not using a local scope named function.

So we have the following code:

```
MongooseModel.virtual('propName').set(function(inputString) {

  this.myValue = parseInput(inputString) 

  this.myValue = this.myValue || inputString.split(',').map(size=> { 
    return {size : buildSize(size)}
  })

  function parseInput(stringToParse) {
     ....body    
  }

  function buildSize(sizeToBuild) {
     ....body    
  }
}
```

My claim is:

1) You shouldn't use local function unless we really need closures (have a call back, need to return a function etc). It just creates overhead of re-creating the function each time.

2) Having a local function that is called only once makes no sense, you pay for overhead, have to jump into another section in the code, etc.

His claim:

1) it different part of the code, it it looks more structured.

Id love some of the JS guys to chime in, what do you think? 
(all the functions are not long 4-5 lines).

Comment: This is too opinion-based for Stack Overflow's format.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder wouldn't there be a definitive answer to this? At least on the considerations of local functions?

Comment: No, there isn't. Creating functions is *very* fast. Breaking code into small pieces is a well-established way of making it maintainable. But having functions with side-effects (one possible consequence of making them closures over the local context) is a well-established way of making it *un*maintainable. There are lots of pros and cons involved, there's no one answer that fits all situations, and one person's opinion about where lines should be drawn will necessarily be different from someone else's.

Comment: From an optimization point of view, as soon as you don't need to inherit from the context (this or a variable), it's best to move the function declaration outside the context.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is - of course - right but it is nevertheless an interesting topic which just can't be *answered* on a general level and probably not on a more concrete level either. But their is definitely room for an interesting discussion which would probably be well suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).